# The cause for sudden battery discharge?

Tags: battery-life

I've bought already used phone (XCover 3 VE) half a year, but I didn't use it much, now it became my primary phone so I wanted to test the battery (poor reflex on my side).

So I turned off all services, apps, I removed SIM card, only SD card was present. And I turned on screen once a day to check the battery life.

Each day the reading was around 3% less than day before. On the third week the last readout following this pattern was 43%, and on the next day 10%.

My naive assumption is that if battery is used it shows faster discharge, but in even pace. But here it is 3% day after day, and all of the sudden 33% drop in single day. Battery cells are completely broken?

When charging it looks like it charges linearly from 0% to 100% (without gaps in 10%-43% range).

Anyway, I see battery is bad, but I am curious what is the nature/cause of it?

*I hoped Android will show full history of previous days, but once I charged it again it shows only period from last full charge, which translates to 2 hours back, not even days.*